# Using php and MySQL I'm trying to create a SELECT statement to search a database table

Tags: php, mysql

PHP Code:

```
$param_term = $_REQUEST["term"] . '%';

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `code` FROM icd_ten_codes WHERE code LIKE '$param_term'";
```

Table Data to Search:

- A000 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae
- A001 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor

My issue is the wildcard %. When I search for "Cholera" I get no results displayed because the wildcard is picking up the A000 or A001 before it gets to Cholera. Is there a way to modify the $param_term so that I can skip over the A000/A001 so it sees the Cholera?

I tried using:

```
$param_term = $_REQUEST["term"] . '_  ';
```

No avail.

Comment: Put a `%` at the start of the search term too

Comment: Are you searching a column "A000 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01" for "Cholera%" ? Then it will not match and you need to use "%Cholera%'. Also look up sql injection which is a **very** critical issue.

Comment: P.s. you _must_ read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement urgently and correct your code because this version is a sitting duck for hackers and also is vulnerable to simple syntax errors due to the naive approach. Not sure where you learned to do it this way but you certainly shouldn't study from there again

Comment: Its not just Cholera, but many other conditions. I'm basically trying to skip over the first 6 characters in the string because all of the conditions start with a letter(A-Z) followed by 3-4 numbers.

Comment: Well try what we said, then.  Add a `%` to the start of the search term. Then it'll match anything _containing_ that term, not just anything starting with that term.

Comment: `substr(code, 7)` would skip first 6 characters.

Comment: Just wanted to thank all of you. I took sanitization methods and added. Appreciate all of you.

Comment: @CodyLong Escaping or parameterized queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're composing your SQL LIKE statement to search for strings that start with $_REQUEST["term"] and have whatever else after. What you need to do is compose it to search for strings that *start with* whatever, then $_REQUEST["term"], and then have whatever else after:

```
$param_term = '%'.$_REQUEST["term"].'%'
```

edit: As the comments above have mentioned, while this will solve your current problem, maintaining this code will likely generate a HUGE amount of problems if malicious actors manage to send requests to your application. Please sanitize any inputs before you send them to the database

Comment: Thanks JB3. I got it to work properly. I also added sanitation to the code base.